# RPC FundRawTransaction: FeeRate

Tags: json-rpc, bitcoin-unlimited

I want to pass `feerate` argument to Bitcoin Unlimited while using `fundrawtransaction`.

I tried

```
fundrawtransaction ["020000000001e80300000000000017a914f65d061c8966ae9d0d6add32879a492d99bce5848700000000" {"feeRate":0.00001}]
```

However, it says

```
Error: Error parsing JSON:{feeRate:0.00001}]
```

How can I pass the `feeRate` argument like [these lines](https://github.com/decred/atomicswap/blob/70f795e/cmd/btcatomicswap/main.go#L412-L424) (`param0=02000...`, `param1=feerate`) do, but using Core's RPC Debug window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little research, it appears that the syntax is valid for Core ([these lines](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/bfb270a/src/wallet/rpcwallet.cpp#L2873-L2893)), but Bitcoin Unlimited doesn't have that code.